# wordpress contact form 7 modal form after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to send a form (in COntact form 7) after filling in form and then there must show a modal window, i did it but i don't need this form show up on mobile devices if (window.width < 768) it has to show

## modal_call_two - is a modal window.

on_sent_ok: "jQuery('#modal_call_two').show();"

Comment: i know that you wrote it right but it doesn't work :(                                   on_sent_ok:  "function(){if (jQuery(window).width() > 768){
     jQuery('#modal_call_two').show();
}};"

Comment: is this code that you posted part of a bigger snippet of code? its difficult to guess with out more info

Comment: no, that the whole code for this, i think maybe i make a mistake when write exactly in contact form 7

Comment: oh, wait you are wrapping it in a function? why do that? it will never be called just use the code exactly as in my answer `on_sent_ok: "if(jQuery(window).width() > 768){ jQuery('#modal_call_two').show(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check the width of the window

```
if (jQuery(window).width() >= 768){
     jQuery('#modal_call_two').show();
}
```

Comment: i saw it in api documentation                                                        on_sent_ok: "function(){alert('hello world');}"